# Rack app error handling request {HEAD /health } SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

After continuous running of my RAILS application on puma server for 3 to 5 days, 
i'm getting below error: in "puma.stderr.log" file, which is causing to reach the log file size more than 100GB+ in 2 days

```
Rack app error handling request {HEAD /health } 
#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:8:in 'respond_to?'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:8:in 'respond_to?'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:8:in 'respond_to?'

(~= logging this same lines for 15000 to 20000 times in log file)

/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:8:in 'respond_to?'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-contrib-1.7.0/lib/rack/contrib/sendfile.rb:100:in 'call'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in 'call'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in 'call'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in 'call'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:632:in 'handle_request'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:446:in 'process_client'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in 'block in run'
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in 'block in spawn_thread'
```

my PUMA configuration:

```
app_path = Rails.root.to_s
workers         Integer( ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads         9,32 # Min and Max threads per worker

preload_app!

environment     'production'
port            3000
bind            "unix://#{app_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
stdout_redirect "#{app_path}/log/puma/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_path}/log/puma/puma.stderr.log", false # Logging

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile         "#{app_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path      "#{app_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"

activate_control_app
```

Can anyone help me on this please, I'm unable to trace the exact issue to fix this??

Comment: Did you do any changes in the code recently?

Comment: No, it's working fine in my local development environment. but giving this error in production server

Comment: I'm not able to get where exactly the issue is... "/health" is my middle ware to check whether service is running or not. This service was hitting in my server on every 10 seconds

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Moyom, were you able to solve this? Having the same problem.